# Calculus by Apostol Exercise 5.5 Problem 17

Tags: calculus

> There is a function $f$, defined and continuous for all real $x$, which satisfies the equation of the form $$\int_0^x f(t)\,dt = \int_x^1 t^2f(t)dt + \frac{x^{16}}{8} + \frac{x^{18}}{9} + c,$$

I tried to differentiate both sides giving me $f(t) = t^2 f(t) + 2x^{15} + 2x^{17}$, and $f(t) = (2x^{15}+2x^{17})/(1-x^2)$. The answer should be $2x^{15}$, I can't think of any way how to make it happen. Any help?

Comment: The derivative of $\int_{a}^{x}F(t)$ is $F(x)$. But then the derivative of $\int_{x}^{a}F(t)=-\int_{a}^{x}F(t)$ must be $-F(t)$. You didn't write that minus sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{1}t^2f(t)dt=\color{red}{-}x^2f(x).$$
So, $$f(x)=-x^2f(x)+2x^{15}+2x^{17}\Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{2x^{15}(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}.$$

Comment: Oh, I see! Because the derivative of F(1) is zero so we are left with -x^2 f(x). Thanks!

Comment: @shinobi20: Yes! You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

When you differentiate the equation:
$$f(x)=\large{\color{#a00}{-}}x^2f(x)+2x^{15} + 2x^{17}$$
and you continue the calculation

Comment: How come f is a function of w on the left side and x on the right side, shouldn't it be f(x) = -x^2f(x) + 2x^15 +2x^17???

Comment: yes it's just atypo